# Php + Urban Airship + Amazon EC2 Server

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to implemnet a push notification server.

I'm using:
php + Urban Airship + Amazon EC2 Server.

When I try to run the php libary of urban airship I get an error (500).

I think I need to install the HTTP_Request package on my server.

Can anyone explain me how to do it?

Comment: I think you need to look in your Apache log first, or at the text of the error if the error 500 is on Urban Airship's servers.

Comment: Implement Push yourself. It's easy.

Comment: https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/60923-troubleshooting-http-status-codes

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue a while back.
Urban airship is using HTTP_Request.
You can install it either via Pear:

```
pear install HTTP_Request
```

or your package manager:

```
yum install php-pear-HTTP-Request
```

on Debian, Ubuntu and Centos:

```
apt-get install php-http-request
```

Also it seems that the library generates some notices so you might also want to set error_reporting to E_ERROR or E_WARNING